# How do you string a variable together along with a string in PHP?

Tags: php, html

So I have a variable in PHP that I would like to print along with an html tag but I am very new to PHP and I can't seem to get the syntax right

My goal is to output/print the following

```
<div class="post-block" style="background-image:url(Whatever image here);">
```

My code is below:

```
    $feature_posts = the_sub_field('feature_image_post');

      if ( get_sub_field('post-feature') == "" )  {       
        echo '<div class="post-block" style="background-image:url(' .$feature_posts");>';
        echo '</div>'; 
      }
```

Comment: have a look here http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Almost there. You just need `.'` instead of `"` after `$feature_posts`. `.` is the concatenation operator, and `'` will match the closing quote after the div closing bracket.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the concatenation operator and the closing single quote after your variable:

```
$feature_posts = the_sub_field('feature_image_post');

if ( get_sub_field('post-feature') == "" )  {       
    echo '<div class="post-block" style="background-image:url(' . $feature_posts . ')">';
    echo '</div>'; 
}
```

To keep the format more readable you can use double quotes to allow variables in your string. Just have to remember escaping the quotes within the markup:

```
$feature_posts = the_sub_field('feature_image_post');

if ( get_sub_field('post-feature') == "" )  {       
    echo "<div class=\"post-block\" style=\"background-image:url($feature_posts)\">";
    echo '</div>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make that.

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++){ ?>
    <div class="post-block" style="background-image:url(<?php echo the_sub_field('feature_image_post') ?>);"></div>

<?php } ?>
```

This a sample how you can do.

Comment: it needs to be within the loop so would it be closer to `echo '<?php the_sub_field("feature_image_post")>)'`